# How to aggregate the responses of two web services using spring integration

Tags: soap, spring-integration, soap-client

I am calling two webservices using spring-integration as shown below:

application-context.xml

```
<int:chain input-channel="requestChannelForHolidayService"
    output-channel="outputChannelForHolidayService">
    <int-ws:outbound-gateway
        uri="http://localhost:8080/holidayService/holidayService" marshaller="marshaller"
        unmarshaller="marshaller" />
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="requestChannelForAccount"
    output-channel="outputChannelForAccount">
    <int-ws:outbound-gateway
        uri="http://localhost:8080/spring-webservices-sample/endpoints"
        marshaller="marshaller1" unmarshaller="marshaller1" />
</int:chain>
```

Testrunner.java

```
ApplicationContext context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");  
    MessageChannel channel=(MessageChannel) context.getBean("requestChannelForHolidayService",MessageChannel.class);  
    HolidayRequest request=new HolidayRequest();
    BigInteger b1=new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger b2=new BigInteger("50");
    request.setEmpId(b1);
    request.setDays(b2);
    System.out.println("sending request");
    System.out.println("request sent");
    channel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(request).build());

    ApplicationContext context1 =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");  
    MessageChannel channel1=(MessageChannel) context1.getBean("requestChannelForAccount",MessageChannel.class);  
    AccountDetailsRequest request2=new AccountDetailsRequest();
    request2.setAccountNumber("12345");
    System.out.println("sending request2");
    System.out.println("request sent2");
    channel1.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(request2).build());
```

Now I need to combine the output of 'outputChannelForHolidayService' and 'outputChannelForAccount'.Can anyone help out for acheiving this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use two application contexts; put them in the same context. Set the `correlationId` header on the messages; send both results to an aggregator with `release-strategy-expression="size == 2"`.

Consider using a [Messaging Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway) instead of sending to channels. Something like:

```
Collection<Object> process(@Payload Object[] requests, @Header("correlationId"), String correlation);
```

Then in the context, have...

```
gateway->splitter->payload-type-router->
    request1Channel->ws->toAgg
    request2Channel->ws->toAgg

toAggChannel->aggregator
```

If you omit the `output-channel` from the aggregator, the result will go back to the gateway.